# Is it possible to look up box files and folders with path

Tags: box-api, box, boxapiv2

I would like to know whether its possible to look up to files and folders stored in box with the path of it like in ***dropbox***.  Retrieving id of the files or folders we want to access/manage seems like an overhead. Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is not possible to access Box files and folders by path. The file/folder ID is returned to you when the item is created and it does not change over time, so you might consider saving the ID if the file/folder will be frequently accessed.

Box is not unique in this regard. [Here's a useful comparison](http://lukasmartinelli.ch/cloud/2014/07/21/cloud-storage-apis-compared.html) of how several major storage services handle file/folder identification (among other things).